# Crystal Reports 11: Finding where data is being filtered out

Tags: crystal-reports

I am not a Crystal Reports developer.

In a legacy Crystal Report, I have been asked to find out why some Rows of data are being excluded from the Report Output at run time.

I copied the SQL behind the report and when I ran it in SQL Server Management Studio, those rows are *not* excluded. This is what leads me to conclude that there is a filter in the report itself that is excluding certain rows.

My question:
What are the different places in Crystal Reports 11 that I should look to find if any filtering is going on at run time?

I have looked at Formula fields, Selection formulas, Parameter Fields ... but though I have seen various code in those places, I have not found anything that looks like it will limit the output.

I would appreciate any pointers/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If the report SQL is the same as the one you checked in SSMS (including record selection formula , which will be the WHERE clause) , check report's details section suppression formula. A details row might be suppressed based on some row values

Answer (score 0):

Besides section suppression, look at:
Report, Selection Formula, Record...
Report, Selection Formula, Group...
Database joins

Comment: Hi @MilletSoftware. Could you possibly elaborate a little on your comment? For instance, I don't understand what "look at: Report, Selection Formula, Record... Report, Selection Formula, Group... Database joins" means exactly. The interface is new to me so I don't know how to navigate to the various locations in which 'filters' could be placed.

Comment: It means go to the 'Report' menu, find the 'Selection Formula' menu below that, find the 'Record...' menu below that...